# Cannot get past Dell "setup" while installing Ubuntu on a 160GB hard drive

Tags: dell, live-usb, ubuntu-studio

I was given a Dell Dimension e521, no operating system and a mysterious 160GB hard drive. By using a USB flash drive to install Ubuntu Studio 14.04, I cannot get past the built-in BIOS. I keep getting a message +corrupted registry, .../windows/system32/config/windows"

Wouldn't the Ubuntu installer bypass any Windows XP if there even is an operating system installed at all? Booting without the Ubuntu USB give me a simple response: "no operating system". I have installed Linux including Ubuntu on a number of PC laptops without any trouble. The current hard drive can be wiped clean and reformatted (there's nothing needed on it).

How do I get past the /windows/system32/config/windows? I have no Windows installer. I only want to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the computer does not fully support booting from a USB stick, even in the off chance it supports booting from an external hard drive. Go into the bios (I believe it is F2 on dells) and go over to the boot page/tab. Move the USB option up above all hard drives. If it does not support booting from USB, then try burning a DVD and boot from that.

Comment: I will try moving USB up to 1st start up choice.

Comment: I did this, still not work. If the Hard Drive itself is bad, will it show the same message? I have also tried installing from a DVD,nothing, not evn the Live Ubuntu showed up.

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping the hard drive with another hard drive, preferably either an empty hard drive or a data hard drive that does not have either an operating system or a bootloader already installed on it. By "swapping" I mean putting another hard drive into an empty hard drive bay in the Dell Dimension, and then switching the cables from the old hard drive to the new hard drive.

In order to boot the computer from a USB flash drive you need to enter your BIOS setup utility by pressing one of these keys, usually: <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> as soon as the motherboard splash screen appears when the computer is booting. Dell computers usually use the <kbd>F2</kbd> key to access the BIOS. In the BIOS menu, change the boot order so that the USB flash drive, which is usually called USB-HDD in newer computers, is the first entry in the boot sequence, and then save your new BIOS settings and exit the BIOS setup utility.

Comment: I am now using the DVD drive to install an OS, I have also found an unregistered copy of XP just to check the HD. If none of this works, I will grab a HD from another machine I now have and try to swap it in.

Comment: Before you grab that hard drive, you should check the contents of the drive to make sure that you have made a backup of anything on that drive that you want to keep. Consider how much time it takes to make just one document and then multiply it by the number of files on the drive to get a rough idea about why backing up files is so important.