# Booting from live Linux DVD on Dell Latitude D830

Tags: boot, dell, dvd

The bootup order has the DVD at Number Four, however there is no other OS on the hard drive. I do not see any option on the Dell D830 Latitude laptop that will allow it to see the Linux DVD, altho it is in the drive. Is there a utility to allow access to the bios?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get past Dell "setup" while installing Ubuntu on a USB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488752/cannot-get-past-dell-setup-while-installing-ubuntu-on-a-usb)

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the machine and for a few seconds after it has started to reboot you should see on the screen "Press F1 or Press F2 or Press Delete to enter the BIOS." After you get into the BIOS set the DVD Drive to boot priority 1 then save and exit the BIOS. If the Startup Disk was made properly it should work. After installation remember to set the HDD to boot priority 1.